# Kotlin: How to get user Email/Username from firebase on Android

Tags: algorithm, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am creating a project whereby a user database is automatically created on signup for the first time. It functions well, however, i want the information on the database to display the User's Email or Name and not uid as shown below.

[image: Image from firebase]

the only reason i am using uid is because i have failed to successfully manage to call a function that enables me to display it.

here is my code:

they belong in an Object activity so the first 2 code examples are object codes

1. initiate the firebase setup

   ```
   object FirestoreUtil {

    private val FirestoreInstance: FirebaseFirestore by lazy { FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() }

    private val currentUserDocRef: DocumentReference
      get() = FirestoreInstance.document(
        "users/${FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
            ?: throw NullPointerException("UID is null.")}"
      )
   ```

2.THIS is used on the signup button to create a new users database on launching;

```
 fun InitCurrentUserIfFirsttime(onComplete: () -> Unit) {
    currentUserDocRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->

        if (!documentSnapshot.exists()) {
            val newUser = User(
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.displayName ?: "",
                "", "",null, mutableListOf()
            )
            currentUserDocRef.set(newUser).addOnSuccessListener {
                onComplete()
            }
        }else{
                onComplete()

        }

    }
}
```

3.My data class;

```
data class User(val name: String,
             val bio: String,
             val age: String,
             val profilePicturePath: String?,
             val registrationTokens: MutableList<String>) {
constructor(): this("", "", "",null, mutableListOf())
```

}

4.from my signup button;

```
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(signuptv.text.toString(),  signupPassword.text.toString())
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                FirestoreUtil.InitCurrentUserIfFirsttime {
                    startActivity(Intent(this, LogInActivity::class.java))
                    finish()
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
```

Comment: So I haven't tried this my self, but I believe that you would be able to change this generating the document and assigning an ID to it as in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document), this way you could use the email to set the document ID

Comment: not working. even the description in the site gives barely any info

Comment: you know, you are totally right, I missed that you were using this [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) , after looking at the documentation, it looks like you can not change the document name, so the solution would be to upload it and re upload it with the help of the first comment documentation (naming yourself the document).

But this would leave the method createUserWithEmailAndPassword unusable as there could exist different duplicates if a user creates an account twice.

Comment: I believe that the best shot right here is to ask for a Feature request on that library for firestore, I believe you can use [this form](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) in order to submit a feature request. If you need this, you could use custom code, I believe that you could [search](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data) first for documents with that email, and if there is a user with that user email, return that the user already exists.

Comment: @LuisManuel thank you sir, this has been rather enlightening even though you didn't have a fixed clear solution. Thanks. I wouldnt mind if you give my question an up-vote to be featured on other peoples timeline